# HTML5 audio - get time played of a sound object (howler.js)

Tags: javascript, howler.js

Im playing some HTML5 audio using the Howler.js library.

Currently im able to determine the total length of the audio file with `sound.duration();` however im not sure how to create a timer to show how much time that has been played.

I create a simple sound object like so:

```
var sound = new Howl({
    src: ['sound.ogg', 'sound.mp3', 'sound.wav'],
    autoplay: true,
    loop: false,
    volume: 1,
    onload: function() {
        var totalSoundDuration = sound.duration();
    },
    onplay: function(getSoundId) {
        //sound playing
    },
    onend: function() {
        //sound play finished
    }
});
```

I can't seem to find any method within the library (?) to check for currentTime so I can update my timer function.

An alternative route could simply be to trigger/toggle a setInterval upon `onplay:` like:

```
var currentTimeTracker=setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    timePlayed++;

    $("#time" ).html(timePlayed);
}
```

Not sure if that would be a good approach? Any suggestions?

Howler.js ref:
https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0#global-core-properties

Answer (score 2):

According to http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library `sound.pos()` should get the current position. The `pos`method can get or set, depending on whether you pass through the optional `position` parameter.

Comment: Since you are using howler.js 2.0, the `seek` method will work the same as `pos` in this instance: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0#seekseek-id.

Comment: Thanks @JamesSimpson that's correct for the v2.0 branch. I think the v2.0 docs need updating as references are still made to `pos` as being the playback position rather than the 3D spatial position: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0#pauseid